# Input 12:00 PM on VBA Userform Combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have this vba userform combobox that shows time range. In the rowsource, i have inputted 12:00 PM. But everytime i click 12:00 PM in the combobox, it shows 12:05 AM instead. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()
    ComboBox5.value = Format(ComboBox5, "hh:mm")
End sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use click event instead of change event

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_Click()
    Dim t As Double

    With ComboBox5
        t = Val(.List(.ListIndex))
        .Value = Format(t, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Dy.Lee The above code can't replace the procedure OP published as his own, to wit, `Private Sub ComboBox5_Change() ComboBox5.value = Format(ComboBox5, "hh:mm") End sub `. It will also not be helpful if the user enters a time which isn't in the combo box's list.

Answer (score 0):

A ComboBox handles text strings. Excel records time as a fraction of 1. 12:00 PM = 0.5 (half a day). Therefore the first question is what you loaded into your ComboBox. Did you load a number like "0.5" - as string, of course, because the ComboBox only takes strings (VBA may have done the conversion for you without notification) - or as a text string, like "12:00 PM". Either way, the ComboBox will hold whatever you have in the RowSource range.

The other question is how the ComboBox converts the string in its list to the string it displays. Conversion is done by means of the cell format in Excel and the *Format()* function in VBA. The fact that a different time is shown points to a conversion taking place. Look for code that runs on one of the ComboBox's events, for example the Change event.

T take control I suggest that you import text strings into your ComboBox, like "12:00 PM". If you load text strings the drop-down will show them correctly both in the list and in the Cbx. When you want to use a Cbx value in calculations use the *TimeValue()* function for conversion.

```
Dim MyTime As Double
MyTime = TimeValue(ComboBox1.Value)
```

Will assign the correct numberr to *MyTime* if the string in the Cbx represents a time in a format your computer understands. The best way to make sure of this is to store the values as true Times (meaning 0.5 for 12:00 PM) and convert these values to a time string when you load them into the Cbx. Use code like `Format(0.5, "hh:mm AM/PM")` for the conversion. Replace "0.5" with a variable of double data type. If you wish to continue using the *RowSource* range, set it up with formulas like this in it, `=Text(A1, "hh:mm AM/PM")` where A1 holds the true time.

Comment: Hello, currently i use this format code
ComboBox5.value = Format(ComboBox5, "hh:mm") how should i modify it?

Comment: Don't use this code. Follow the suggestions I gave above in setting up the Cbx.

Comment: Actually i'm a bit confused. Where should i put the format code? After my time code?

Comment: If you load the the Cbx from RowSource you should have texts there. If you load the Cbx using the `Add` method convert the times read from RowSource at that time. Any times the user enters (if you allow that instead of selection) should be in string format already. They may need verification but no conversion. Once you're sure everything around your Cbx is in string format you only need to convert when you want to write back to the sheet or do calculations with the entered times.