# Change ComboBox display

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a ComboBox that displays different times of the day to select from, the problem is that once the time is selected the format of the value changes

When I open the ComboBox the time appears in the following format which is correct

[image]

But then for example if I select 8:00 the following appears

[image]

How can I make it so that it appears as 08:00 rather than 0.33333 ?

I tried the following already but didn't manage to fix the problem with that

```
ComboBox5.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(ComboBox5.Value, "hh:mm")
```

The way that the ComboBox is obtaining these values is through a defined range, so I use RowSource to refer to where these values are located at. These values are also formatted as hh:mm

[image]

Comment: How did you add these values? Are they actual time values?

Comment: I have a list in another sheet with the times, (these are also formatted as hh:,mm) and then the ComboBox refers to them through RowSource

Comment: @jvdv I have edited the question to add more information to the question

Comment: Use click event instead of change event. Refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61493230/input-1200-pm-on-vba-userform-combobox/61495752#61495752)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by using

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()

ComboBox5.Value = VBA.Format$(ComboBox5.Value, "hh:mm")

End Sub
```